# What is this bug?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification, arachnology

I recorded a video of this bug:

[image]

https://youtu.be/0eoWfHLEo7A

I counted 8 legs, the front legs are a little curved. The drawing on the flat back is dark and looks like the image of Jesus with some light from behind, hahahaha. I found it on the curtain of my bedroom. I believe it belongs to some tree where it can use its camouflage. Can anyone identify it?

Location: Valencia, Spain.

Comment: Where (geographically speaking) was it found?

Comment: Grao de Gandia, Valencia, Spain.

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need any assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it looks a lot like a European Pigeon Tick (*Argas reflexus*).

[image]

They infest pigeons and they die when infesting humans, which they only do if they are very hungry (yours looks hungry though).
May also transmit diseases.

**Edit:**
It could also be an Blyborough Tick (*Argas vespertilionis*). They infest bats and are a little rounder in shape but look otherwise similar.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm glad I killed it in time. Although it went inside a hole and I had to stick something to kill it.

Comment: By the way, we live close to a park full of bats and some have tried getting in. So, it is highly likely to be an _Argas vespertilionis_

Answer (score 6):

My best guess is a soft-bodied tick, perhaps of the *Ornithodoros* genus, although the determination of the species is a little more difficult. Though, if it's *O. erraticus* they're known for causing african swine fever in Spain and Portugal [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithodoros_erraticus).

[Ornithodoros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithodoros)

In response to the comments, here's a [link](http://tickapp.tamu.edu/tickbiology.php) from Texas A&M which notes the ticks pump waste+water back out into the host, and this is why they transmit so many infections.

Comment: That wiki page says "The opening between the midgut and hindgut has been lost, making the ticks unable to pass digestive waste products out of their bodies", so do these ticks just fill up with waste?

Comment: If that is true, no doubt why they carry diseases and viruses.

Comment: @user137 I've updated the answer to respond to your comment. The ticks pump the waste back into the host.

Comment: @Kendall That makes these ticks even worse.