# Identification of a small flat bug

Tags: species-identification, arachnology, invertebrates

So for the last few days I have been noticing these small bugs in my bathroom -- they don't appear frequently, and I see them once or twice a month. 
The characteristics and behavior I observed are as follows :

- They RARELY move around.
- They are extremely flat, like totally flat
- Some are small, some are big (but still the overall size is small)

Below are the pictures : 
[image: bug]

I cropped this picture since the original size was 5mbs and the limit was only 2. If anyone wants the original image I can inbox them .

Appreciate any help or suggestion with this :)

**EDIT 2**
I am adding another image for greater clarity , hope this helps 
[image]

**Edit 3**

Location: Karachi Pakistan.

Size: 0.2-0.4 cm

As for nearby animal populations: No not much, just the usual street cats.

For a few months these bugs were gone until recently they have started to appear in the bathroom, like I see them 2-3x a month just sitting still for hours and hours.

Comment: The image is just blurry enough that I can't tell if it has 6 legs or 8. It almost reminds me of a tick. But ticks don't normally infest bathrooms.

Comment: It has 8 legs , I can upload another good quality image but the size limit 2mbs , the original image is around 7mbs in size.
Yes thats what I originally thought that it was a tick but they are always seen in the bathrooms just staying at the wall for hours and hours without movng

Comment: Do you have a pigeon problem? Do you live near a cave or visit caves? Do you interact with poultry birds?

Comment: It seems my comment was removed , anyway i'll again comment:
My location is Karachi Pakistan , its around 0.2 to 0.4 cm in length and mostly the typical street cats around BUT now that you have mentioned it yes there are pigeons around my window , they sleep at a small hedge just above my window sometimes and at the bathroom window too

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/31383/16866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely an arachnid and mite (subclass [Acari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acari)), and very likely a member of the order [*Parasitiformes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitiformes), of which there are more than 100,000 species!!

Your specimen brings to mind the family [Argasidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argasidae) (the "soft ticks" -- so called because they lack a hard [scutum](http://www.idph.state.il.us/envhealth/tickkey.htm)).

Specifically, your specimen reminds me of *Argas reflexus*, the pigeon tick. (which [has been found](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15815109) to be an increasing pest and human concern in urban settings).

[image]

<sup>Credit: [Milan Kudlička](https://www.biolib.cz/en/image/id247800/)</sup>

Based on the size of your specimen, I would guess you're looking at a non-adult stage.

**However, this is *just* a guess, and I will try to explore other species in this general group to see if I can come up with a better-supported guess.**

(By the way: any pigeons living nearby??)

Comment: I think you are correct with this , its not exactly like this what you posted but its very very much like them . Yup there are pigeons and maybe those are pigeon ticks like what you mentioned

Comment: Well there you go! The presence of pigeons outside your window makes sense. Please upvote accept the answer if you find it acceptable. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sure , thank you for this , just one last question are they dangerous ? Like do I need to be concerned about them ? and any tips on how to remove them ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer -- please upvote, too, if you think it's deserving. As for dangerous: see the link in my answer's 3rd paragraph (you'll likely have to translate from Italian). There's evidence that repeated bites can increase your odds of developing anaphylactic shock and possibly being exposed to harmful pathogens (though no clear example of human pathogens seems to exist in this species from what I've seen). For removal: the pigeons will have to go or the ticks will keep showing up. However, any ticks remaining after removing pigeons will still be looking for blood...

Comment: I voted but since I am new the vote is not showing as I need toto have a repo greater than 15 , but I have voted :) and thank you for the suggestions :)