# what is this bug ? i found it on bed 2 times

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology, arthropod

What is this 1mm long bug I found on my bed in Egypt?

[image: front photo]

Here is its back photo

[image: back photo]

Comment: It's a soft-bodied tick (family Argasidae). See [Identification of a small flat bug](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/81026/16866) for an example. Without providing us your location, nobody can give you a definitive ID. Please [edit] your post with more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identification of a small flat bug](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81026/identification-of-a-small-flat-bug?noredirect=1&lq=1)